# How do I click a button after the new page has fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-console

I have got several pages. Page 1 contains a button which redirects to page 2. Page 2 contains a button which redirects to page 3. I started on page 1 and wanted to write some script to finish a 2-step process to open page 3.

The "v4lnk" button exists as it appears on the first page. However, the "binBtn_btn" button does not upon running, as it appears on the second page.

I have got some code below, but every time I run it, it reports that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
" for the document.getElementById("binBtn_btn") elem.

I have tried `setInterval`, `window.onload()`.

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("v4lnk");
links[0].click();

setInterval(() => {
  const button = 
      document.getElementById("binBtn_btn");
  if (button) {
    button.click();
  }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Well then your `getElementsByClassName()` selector is not matching the elements you think exist.

Comment: Its not possible to select element from another page